# Error using numpy.polyfit in a cx_freezed program

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, cx-freeze

I'm trying to build a standalone program using `cx_freeze` in Python 3.4.

When I execute my program through Python there is absolutely no problems (0 errors, everything works), but when I open the `.exe` file created with `cx_freeze`, my GUI (Qt) just closes when I'm calling the `polyfit` function frin `numpy`.

I think that it's not just an error of importation, because when I try something like "numpy.pi + 2" after `cx_freeze`, it works fine.

Any ideas?

*Notes:*

- I though it was because my function was a bit complicated, but when I tried `polyfit([1,2,3], [4,5,6], 2)`, I encounter the same problem
- Using `scipy.polyfit` result in the same problem

Comment: what does "close up" mean exactly? Perhaps you should try to catch / display / report the exception, which is raised.

Comment: By "close-up" i mean that my GUI just shut down. I tried to use :
 try :
      polyfit([1,2,3], [4,5,6], 2)
 except Exception as e:
      print(e)

But it has no effect...

Comment: @kxr , the problem is that when i'm using python (and not the .exe) it works. And when i launch the .exe through console i have nothing returned by the program (even when i try to raise an exception)

Comment: Qt.  Are you using Linux?

Comment: Nop, i'm using windows 10 x64. My problem was just the libraries which were not installed properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem with :

- uninstalling all the packages numpy/scipy
- reinstall the whl with pip (numpy-1.11.1+mkl-cp34-cp34m-win32.whl and scipy-0.18.0-cp34-cp34m-win32.whl)
- install numpy-1.9.2-win32-superpack-python3.4.exe from https://sourceforge.net/projects/numpy/files/NumPy/1.9.2/

And now everything works :)